# How can I keep my reheated Oats from sticking together?

Tags: reheating, oats

I usually make steel cut oats in a rice cooker (1:3 ratio of oats and water) and generally have a couple of servings left over. When I try to reheat in the microwave it comes out all congealed together in small little chunks. Even if I put a little milk before microwaving still doesn't seem to work - The milk stays settled on the bottom of the heated bowl and the oats are still clumped together.  Any Tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to really beat the milk into it. Start with all of the oatmeal in a bowl, and add just a little milk and mush it in with a fork. Keep adding milk a little at a time until you reach the texture you like, then reheat it.

Answer (score 0):

Before you store your remaining cooked oats in the refrigerator, add more hot water to them to make them looser than you would normally would, dare I say soupy. As you go to reheat your oats the next time, you will be removing moisture during the heating process which causes them to stick together and turn gummy.  If they are still sticking together during the reheating process I will stir in hot water or milk until I get the consistency I desire.